# Is a Bayesian posterior kind of like the marginal distribution of a frequentist estimator?

Tags: probability, bayesian, posterior, frequentist

I've been thinking a lot about the relationships between various concepts like hypothesis testing, posterior distributions, and estimators.

If I understand correctly, a frequentist estimator $\hat\theta$ aims to approximate an unknown but constant $\theta$ based on some observed data $X$, or in other words it attempts to optimize some pointwise metric by marginalizing out $X$ (for example unbiasedness, $E_X[\hat\theta(X)-\theta|\theta]=0$ for all $\theta$). Confidence intervals are also implicitly conditioned on the unobserved $\theta$ (i.e. $P(\theta\in[a(X),b(X)]|\theta)=0.95$).

On the other hand, Bayesian posteriors attempt to marginalize out the unknown $\theta$ (as opposed to $X$) according to a prior distribution $P(\theta)$, replacing the "pointwise" estimate $\hat\theta$ with a single posterior distribution $P(\theta|X)$. The answer is simpler because we are assuming more than in the frequentist approach.

Both methods assume the same known data generating distribution $X\sim D(\theta)$.

Am I correct in my interpretation that frequentist methods try to marginalize out $X$ while Bayesian methods try to marginalize out $\theta$?

I found another (the same?) example of this "symmetry": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_decision_rule#Generalized_Bayes_rules

Comment: How confidence intervals are conditioned on $\theta$? Moreover, in frequentist setting $\theta$ is not a random variable, so you couldn't condition on it. It also does not have distribution.

Comment: If you think of theta as a random variable and condition everything on it, it becomes a constant. I was just trying to emphasize that $\theta$ is fixed and you make a separate claim about $\hat\theta$ for each possible value of $\theta$ in the frequentist setting.

Comment: What is claimed "for all values of $\theta$"? What all values? If population is single mean, then you condition on constant?

Comment: It's a claim about the estimator as a function from X to $\mathbb{R}$, when we say it's unbiased we mean $E_X[\hat\theta]=\theta$ for all values of $\theta$ (or it may only be unbiased for some values of $\theta$).

Comment: Because the frequentist estimator does not conceive of $\theta$ as having any kind of probability distribution, it makes no sense to talk of marginal distributions.  When the frequentist *can* justify adopting a probability model for $\theta,$ her techniques include everything that the Bayesian theory uses.

Comment: solved discuss : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182936/bayesian-vs-frequentist-estimation

Answer (score 0):

In Bayesian setting, you are considering the prior distribution of $\theta$, this does let you use Bayes theorem and calculate the conditional probabilities. In frequentist setting you end up with estimate that *depends on* the observed data. In frequentist setting you are not "marginalizing out" the data unless you observed the whole population, otherwise this is still an estimate given single sample. So I would argue that this intuition is not correct.